# SwiftUI List click and row color change only working when clicking on text but not on row

Tags: swiftui

My list displays my array values and when a row is tapped irow t changes colour to show the row selected. In the below code everything works but for some strange reason only when I have .border(.black) on the HStack property.

If I remove the border then only the when I tap on the text does my row colour change and not if I tap on the row where there is not text.

I've tried Button() and contentShape() but it did not work. Although I have a solution, I was wondering how this could be improved.

```
VStack (){
    TextField("Search", text: $searchSite)
        .frame(width: 300, height: 10)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .font(.custom("Raleway", size: 16))
        .padding()
        .background(Color.white)
        .cornerRadius(10) // Add rounded corners
         // Set the frame width to 200
        .padding(.top, 5)
    List {
        ForEach(filteredSites, id: \.self) { siteListDetails in
            HStack {
                Text(siteListDetails.siteName!)
                    .arial16White()
                    .padding(.leading, 16)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)

            }
            .border(.black)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .listRowSeparatorTint(.white)
            .foregroundColor(.clear)
            .listRowBackground(selectedSite == sitesArr.firstIndex(of: siteListDetails) ? Color.blue : Color.clear)
            .onTapGesture {
               selectedSite = sitesArr.firstIndex(of: siteListDetails)
        }
        
       }
    }
    .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    Spacer()
}
.frame(width: 358)
.background(.black)
Spacer()
```

Comment: Using `.contentShape(Rectangle())` should definitely work, try adding it under the `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)` modifier

Comment: That worked, tnx